# Flow passing in record with picklist value into Invocable Apex method causes error

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

When I am trying to pass records prepared into an Invocable Apex method from a flow that have had picklist values set on the record I receive the following error message.

> An Apex error occurred: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD, *Picklist Field*: value not of required type: *Value Set From Flow*: *Picklist Field*

Then I came across the following known Salesforce issue which states there is no workaround - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003fH1QAI

In an effort to find a workaround I first tried casting the field as a String but got the following error.

> An Apex error occurred: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type java:moduleapi.interaction.FlowPicklistValue to String

I then tried JSON serialising and deserialising but then got the following error on deserialising (even untyped)

> An Apex error occurred: System.JSONException: Type unsupported in JSON: moduleapi.interaction.FlowPicklistValue

Seems like there's a special internal type for Flow picklists that doesn't behave well in Apex. Was wondering if there were any ideas to solve this? Or accept that there is no workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out using [String.valueOf()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) actually does the trick in being able to convert it to a String that Apex accepts. Wrote a little utility to help manage this until it gets fixed.

```
public inherited sharing class FlowUtilities {

    private Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> sObjectFieldsMap;

    public FlowUtilities (String sObjectType) {
        this.sObjectFieldsMap = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String> { sObjectType })[0].fields.getMap();
    }

    public List<SObject> cleanPickListValues(List<SObject> records) {
        for (SObject record : records) {
            cleanPickListValues(record);
        }
        return records;
    }

    public SObject cleanPickListValues(SObject record) {
        for (String fieldName : record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().keySet()) {
            if (sObjectFieldsMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST) {
                record.put(fieldName, String.valueOf(record.get(fieldName)));
            }
        }
        return record;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 to this, worked like a charm just plug and play. Ran into this "fun" issue today.