# Flow passing in record with multipicklist value into Invocable Apex method causes error

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I want to pass records prepared into an Invocable Apex method from a flow that have had picklist and multipicklist values set on the record. I want to insert a record from Flow via apex (using InvocableMethod)

Can anyone please share pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? what is the error? You can see example in SF documentation how to invoke apex form flow: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm

Comment: Thanks for response! I have create a flow which has one screen with checkbox group. The checked checkbox values should be stored in Multi Picklist field in Salesforce object. I'm using Apex code to save this.

Comment: You don't have to use apex for that.  You should create picklist choice set with object.multipicklist_field and then use it in the checkbox group source. Next when you insert the record assign the checkbox selection to the field on the new record

Comment: +If for some reason you still need to use apex, then you can still follow my previous comment - assign the selection to the record field and then pass the record as variable to the apex

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have already tried with picklist choice set and assign it but some how its not working. So I moved my code to Apex Action and as per this post picklist needs to save as given in the post which works perfectly fine. 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299459/flow-passing-in-record-with-picklist-value-into-invocable-apex-method-causes-err

My problem is how to save multipicklist values in backend

Comment: Hi, I could manage to do it. Problem was the Multi Picklist data was coming with square brackets. I removed those and save it. It worked perfectly fine. Thanks!